# What is {!text!} in Python?

Tags: python

What do {!info!} and {!input!} do in this python code?

```
s += " {!info!}Down Speed: {!input!}%s" % common.fspeed(status["download_payload_rate"])
```

Taken from: http://git.deluge-torrent.org/deluge/tree/deluge/ui/console/commands/info.py?h=1.3-stable

Thanks.

Comment: just looks like a stylish way of printing on the console to me. Nothing special

Comment: It's not about python. It could be a markup notation to be processed by that `console` instance in some special way like a color applied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They don't mean anything to Python. The string `s` will literally contain `{!info!}`and `{!input!}`. However, that string is later interpreted by Deluge itself to do color formatting — see [ui/console/colors.py](http://git.deluge-torrent.org/deluge/tree/deluge/ui/console/colors.py?h=1.3-stable), specifically `parse_color_string`.